# How to input ampersand with adb shell input?

Tags: android, input, adb, keyboard-events

`adb shell input text "&"` doesn't work, nor does `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_AMPERSAND`.

Related to [question 7789826](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/inputting-events-through-adb-shell).

Comment: Does either of these work? `adb shell input text ^&`, `adb shell input text "^&"`.

Comment: `adb shell "input text \&"`

Comment: I am also using Arch Linux and bash, and Paresh's answer works for me. If it doesn't work for you, I don't know why not... maybe we have different versions of Android or adb. I'm running Cyanogenmod 11. I could try later on my other phone that has Android 4.1.

Comment: `adb shell input text "\&"` works on both of my phones.

Comment: adb 1.0.32, CyanogenMod 11-20141008-SNAPSHOT-M11-hammerhead, Android 4.4.4

Comment: Neither `adb shell input text ^&` nor `adb shell input text "^&"` works.

Comment: Maybe try asking at [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) or the [Android Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
adb shell input text "\&"
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, no matter how many backslashes I add.

Comment: It works for me from Linux. What OS are you using? @AlexHenrie

Comment: @S.Morgenstern Windows 8

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu/zsh and Android M. The reason you need to doubly-escape the string is that [there are two shells: your shell, and the adb shell](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61561).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this in the future, the escape that finally worked from me was not \&, but rather "\&"

as in

```
adb shell echo Macaroni "\&" Cheese
```

and **not**

```
adb shell echo Macaroni \& Cheese
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

For the record, this is on Windows.

Comment: thanks for the answer Anthony, and welcome to StackOverflow!