# Skype URI through adb, can't turn video on by default

Tags: adb, uri, skypedeveloper

I am trying to start a video call on Skype using their URI API, but the video is turned off when the call starts.

They give a clear example how to use it:

`skype:skype.test.user.1?call&amp;video=true`

I am using adb to send the command, so I am using the command:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "skype:someuser?call&video=true"`

This successfully initiates the call, but with video off. I have tried adding the extra parameter using the Android adb extra parameters:

`--es extra_key extra_string_value`

So my full command is

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW --es "video" "true" -d skype:someuser?call`

but this doesn't make the trick.

Comment: If the arguments the Skype app expects are not documented you can try to decompile the app e.g. using Jadx and check the activity class that handles the requests if it accesses the extra arguments or parses the query URL.

Comment: @Robert, I tried this and succesfully decompiled the apk, but i had no luck finding the code that processes the arguments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution thanks to this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25791498/7582025).
The solution is simply to escape the ampersand (&) character inside the quotes!

So, the final command that worked for me is:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "skype:someuser?call\&video=true"
```